# 3 step animation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation

I am trying to work on 3 step animation. Bring in text, make it stay for few seconds and then slide it back.

```
function showAnimation(){
    var id = 1;
    d3.json('/api/'+id, function(error,data){
        $.each(data, function(i,value){
            var dataVal = value;
            function Animation()
            {   
                if(dataVal.value != null){
                    $(".animation").html("<p class='value'>"+dataVal.value+"</p>").addClass('slideInLeft');
                }    
            }
            setInterval(Animation, 5000);
        });
        var delay = setInterval(showAnimation,10000);
    });
}
```

Comment: None of the code shown does any animation. Have you tried using jQuery's animation methods, or is the class that you are adding supposed to trigger a CSS transition, or....? What is the inner setInterval() for?

Comment: @nnnnnn I am using a animate.css plugin and jquery. With this plugin I will have to add a animate class with the effect  like slideInleft

Comment: @nnnnnn I have 5 values for an id number so after 5 values i will need to use some other id and call the api